# I can connect digital ocean droplet via SSH connected in home network but not in work network

Tags: networking, ssh, server, digital-ocean

Scenario...

WiFi Network home = Can connect with my Digital Ocean servers fine via SSH;
WiFi Network work = Can't connect with my Digital Ocean servers via SSH;

WiFi Network work SSH debug:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
```

Anyone?

Comment: Perhaps your employer has some restrictive egress filters on their firewall. have you tried SSH-ing to a different server from there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to  check with nc

```
nc -zvw4 your_host 22
```

If not open - probably 22 port not allowed in your network, you can ask your network administrator about it

on your server make forward from 443 to 22 via iptables, for example:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 22
```

Comment: it's easier to start ssh also on port 443.

Comment: if 443 not used for web server and try to connect with -p 443
`ssh -p 443 your_host`
if 443 already used - try redirect to some high numbered port like 4444

Comment: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: nc -zcw4 192.241.143.202 22
nc: invalid option -- 'c'
This is nc from the netcat-openbsd package. An alternative nc is available
in the netcat-traditional package.

Comment: sorry, my typo
`nc -zvw4`

Comment: nc: connect to 192.241.143.202 port 22 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress

Comment: then try to make redirect or run ssh on another port